# why dialog is not a view in Android

Tags: android, dialog

I am wondering why dialog is not a view. 
From Android developer guide, "The visual content of the window is provided by a hierarchy of views — objects derived from the base View class", but dialog class:

```
public class Dialog implements DialogInterface, Window.Callback,
        KeyEvent.Callback, OnCreateContextMenuListener {
```

is there anyone knows about the reason of the design?

Comment: An activity ain't a view either but the visual content of both is provided by views. Both dialogs as well as activities are windows not views.

Comment: that is helpful for understanding it. Actually, i'd like to find a dialog button by findviewbyid() in instrumentation test. And it is hardly to do that. Any possible?

Comment: Whats the problem? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#findViewById(int)